# SymmetricDS: How to configure router to sync header detail relationship

Tags: router, symmetricds

I have 2 tables

```
HeaderTable: 
Header_ID Header_Status

DetailTable:
Detail_ID Header_ID
```

I want to sync `HeaderTable` based on `Header_Status = A`, this can be done by setting column router `Header_Status=A`

For `DetailTable`, I want to do a checking to sync only if the `Header_ID` has already sync to the target, which means I have to route based on query like `select * from HeaderTable where Header_ID=:Header_ID`

How could I achieve this in the `sym_router`?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try the subselect router which allows for custom queries definition:

```
select node_id
from   sym_node
where  0 < (
  select count(*)
  from   HeaderTable
  where  Header_ID=:Header_ID
  and    Header_Status = A);
```

Comment: How should I construct the query since I do not need to select the external id ?

Comment: I have updated my answer with a subselect query that could be used

Comment: Thanks, this is what I have been looking for. Never thought of using the count to return result. Thank you once again.